# Can I allow standard users to install software when Parental Control is enabled?

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls

I had to set up a time limit to one of the account on my Windows 7 PC. So i had created a standard user account and set up parental control for it. But i want the user to be able to install ANY software without the need for the administrator password. How do i give the standard user privilege to install software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Admin privileges are required to write to the Program Files.

So unless the Programs are designed specifically to install to a different location and write registry keys only to non-restricted registry keys, then you are SOL.

Allowing a user to install applications that would normally require an admin password defeats the whole purpose of a user account.  At install time, they can just go awol with the system.

Comment: How exactly does allowing a user to install applications that would normally require an admin password defeat the whole purpose of a user account?  And what do you mean by awol?  Why can't a user just have time limits and not limit write access to certain folders or registry keys?  I believe this is a lazy answer which goes along with the lazy separation of Windows 7 users into Administators and Standard users.  A standard user is just a user with a certain set of permissions.  Why can't these be adjusted by a good admin?

Comment: Step. 1) Create an install program that fires up a command prompt, which will have the same permissions as the installer. Step 2) ... Step 3) Profit.